# Xamarin Objective C binding: .a within a .a, native linking failed

Tags: c#, objective-c, linker, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to bind an Objective C library in a Xamarin project. First time I'm doing this and without knowing much Objective C it's a real head scratcher.

I've fought with Objective Sharpie and managed to get a project that compiles and seems ok. I'm exposing as little of the library as possible in order to have *something* that works, but when trying to debug on device (it isn't i386 anyway, it's a lib for an external accessory) I get the following linker error:

```
Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class:
_OBJC_CLASS_$_ICAdministration. If '_OBJC_CLASS_$_ICAdministration'
is a protocol from a third-party binding, please check that it
has the [Protocol] attribute in its api definition file, otherwise verify
that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries
are properly linked in. (MT5211)
```

The `ICAdministration` class is part of a library within the library. It is used by my main interfacing class which I bind, but I don't bind any properties or methods that use `ICAdministration`. I've seen some errors in regards to Xamarin 7.2 and have tried adding the `--registrar:legacy` mtouch option, without any luck.

Seems like there are tons of flags or command line options one can use for all sorts of things, but this is really not my turf. I have never even had to deal with a linker before, so naturally the C world is a dark and scary place.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Do I have to bind all of the library I'm using, or is it just OK to bind what I need? Are there any pitfalls I should be aware about? Will wrong binding of properties/classes cause problems if they're not used? Is having nested libraries an issue at all?

EDIT: You might want to know the outer Objective C lib is built for the iOS 7.1 SDK (don't have anything else), and the original lib it wraps around is most likely for iOS 5.

Comment: Can you show the Objective-C header for the ICAdministration declaration? Also note that if one Objective-C library requires another, *both* need to be added to the binding project.

Comment: Yes, all libraries are included. It's also tested with a Objective C-project in Xcode and works fine. It's a proprietary library, so not sure if it's legal for me to post the .h?

Comment: If you have privacy concerns, you can ask contact@xamarin.com about this, they'll will keep everything confidential.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding the [[ProtocolAttribute]](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_types_reference_guide/) to the `ICAdministration` interface in the binding project?

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
[Protocol]
[Model]
Interface ICAdministration {}
```